# How to run AuBio (an Open Source C program) on Visual Studio Express

Tags: c, visual-c++, compilation, aubio

I am trying to get an open source software called [AuBio](http://aubio.org) ( [Source](http://dev.aubio.org/browser) ) to run on Visual studio express but I am having a lot of problems getting it to build.

What I've Done:

I opened a new C/C++ solution on VS Express then copied all the header files in the source folder (SRC) into the "Header Files" filter of my project then copied all the C files in the SRC folder into the "Source Files" filter of my project. I have also downloaded all the 3 [dependencies](http://dev.aubio.org/wiki/Build) required to run AuBio but I do not know where to put them because the "External Dependencies" filter of my project does not seem to want accept them.

Can someone please guide me on how I can go about about building this program?

**Addition**: 
The dependencies are other open source projects; the build instructions for AuBio ( which are [HERE](http://dev.aubio.org/wiki/Build) ) tell me that I need to install the dependencies before I use AuBio but I have no clue how I can do that.

AuBio also provides a pre-compiled version of it's software (it's cross compiled on MingGW32, and is [here](http://aubio.org/download)) which consists of exe files for each major class and dll files for both AuBio and all it's dependencies, but I have no idea how to use these too, when I download and try to run the exe's they refuse to run.

I am really stuck on this can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by filter. Do the header files and source files appear in 'Solution View' of the project? If not you need to add them to the project using the Project, Add Existing Item menu command.

Dependencies:
If they are .lib files then add a line like this to your source files:

```
#pragma comment (lib,"libname.lib")
```

Comment: Visual Studio calls main folder's "filters".So I have put the header files in the "header files" folder and the source code in the "source files" folder, but where do I put the dependencies?

Comment: The dependencies are not lib files but rather other open source projects.See Edited Question